# Nav showing drop down subsites when on _layouts/settings.aspx

Tags: 2010, development, master-page, navigation, sub-site

In both of my custom master pages (both front master page and system master page) I have a navigation control (AspMenu).

On all custom pages and application pages, the nav displays no drop down for subsites (it has subsites, but no sub-subsites under a drop down) EXCEPT from when on _layouts/settings.aspx page. When on this page, the navigation displays the list of sites, but then an additional drop down for each site displaying the subsites.

What's different about this page? How can I restrict this just as I have with the other pages?

Answer (score 2):

Going to leave this up here for anyone that might come across it as I've just worked out what it is.

Settings.aspx overrides the content placeholders that my nav control is in:

- PlaceHolderTopNavBar
- PlaceHolderHorizontalNav

I've just simply brought the nav control outside of these placeholders and hidden the placeholders (settings.aspx will put the nav inside there - and I didn't want to nav controls).